# windows redis doesn't work

Tags: windows, redis, redis-cli, redis-server

Yesterday I downloaded redis from [github](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases) in zip format. In the first place everything seems working fine: the redis-server started up fine, the installing of the service was also going well. But as soon as I started the redis-cli.exe nothing happens, I just get a blank dos window. I also tried connecting using the c# client, but I couldn't connect at all.

I didn't change anything int the .conf files, so the redis.windows.conf is the same file as the .conf file from github.

[image: redis-server.exe]

[image: Redis-cli.exe]

I hope someone can help me further.

Comment: Try running redis-server.exe (without config file) from command-line to see its output and then try to connect with redis-cli.exe - if doesn't work check your firewall (though it is using localhost by default, so this would be rather unlikely, but still possible)

Comment: Tried just running redis-server.exe Still doesn't work